# Permalinks okay some pages but 404 error on others

Tags: permalinks, 404-error

I recently upgraded to WP 3.4.2 and had multiple issues with custom theme. In the course of trying to fix those, permalinks broke for some pages, not others. I get server 404 page not found for the about page and subpage, services page and subpages, and contact page. But pages of home, health-concerns page and subpages, and resources are okay.

I have tried:

1. Undoing and redoing the permalinks. (mod rewrite rules and htaccess is okay). While the pages are all there with page numbers, I must use twentyten theme to access them.
2. Activating twentyten theme. Same 404 behavior. (And it's the server 404, not the WP 404.)
3. Reupdating to 3.4.2.

Site is hosted on GoDaddy; I don't have access to any config or log files. Site is:

http://phoenixhealingarts.net

At one point, I did reupload the database xml backup file. That apparently created a lot of duplicates (custom fields, SEO plugin info), which have since been removed from the database, but possibly could have created problems that persist. I'm looking at the SQL file (exported via phpadmin) but I don't see anything obviously wrong there.

I've been reading posts/forums looking for an answer for many hours now. If you have any ideas, please share them.

Comment: probably there is something wrong in .htaccess?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Wyn, who asked the question, is apparently aware of `.htaccess` and believes it to be fine.

Comment: Have you read [this post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-34-master-list)? & Right now, there's no 404 being dump in the site.

Comment: Right. I have compared the .htaccess file with what it should be several times. It is identical to what it should be. Wyn

Comment: Wyn again: Does anyone know where the permalink information for various pages is stored? I'm wondering if that got corrupted somehow for the half of the pages that are not working. Wyn

Comment: Q to brasofilo: I did not reinstall WP, but I did upgrade from 3.4.1 to 3.4.2. Also, I don't understand your comment "there's no 404 being dump in the site". When I posted this, I might have had twentyten theme with page numbers so at least all content was visible on the site. I have now returned to custom theme with permalinks - so you can see 404 behavior. However, please remember it does the same 404 behavior with twentyten theme.

Comment: Problem fixed YAY. I had to edit the permalinks on the three main pages that were generating the server 404s. In other words, I changed about to about-client-name, changed services to services-page, and changed contact  to contact-us. The 404 behavior went away.

Answer (score 2):

Problem fixed YAY. I had to edit the permalinks on the three main pages that were generating the server 404s. In other words, I changed about to about-client-name, changed services to services-page, and changed contact  to contact-us. The 404 behavior went away. This also fixed the subordinate services pages and the subordinate about page.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going to the page and changing the slug, if you simply go to the page and save again, it will be fine.

That's after you try resetting the permalinks and all that.